# Kivy on_release, to create a new Tab

Tags: python-3.x, tabs, kivy, self

I have this code. Can Someone help me with an `If statement` or any code that can call `on_release`  event to create a new Tab.

```
def load_songs(self, storageLocation):
songs = []


if Path('Books').is_dir():
    for filename in storageLocation.glob('**/*.wav'):
        songs.append(filename)
        # Create  subfolder(Chapter)
    booksdir = [f for f in storageLocation.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]
    for value, Bookfolders in enumerate(booksdir):
      
         #create OneLineListItem(or Button) for each subfolder
        self.root.ids.Books.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=str(Bookfolders), pos_hint={"center_x": 1, "center_y": 1}, ))
 

 > #Here I want a statement that would create a new Tab using the line below whenever the OneLineListItem above is clicked I also intend to close it whenever the user leaves the Tab. 

        self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(title="yea",))
```

Comment: With more research, for anyone who is interested  I found using lambda solved the problem.   `self.root.ids.Books.add_widget(
                    OneLineListItem(text=str(Bookfolders), pos_hint={"center_x": 1, "center_y": 1}, on_release=lambda *args: self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(title=f"Tab {Bookfolders}")) ))`

Comment: got the cue from a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265887/use-on-press-event-to-change-screen-without-kv-language-for-dynamically-created

Comment: But the issue now is only the first item is working. The remaining items in the loop do not seem to be responding